# Events for hyperlink not firing inside usercontrol which is inside raddock

Tags: listview, user-controls, telerik, raddocking

I have a RadStrip in my page. Inside RadStrip, i am placing Raddocks, in which a UserControl page is populated.

Now in my UserControl ascx page, i have an Hyperlink.

While i Click on this Hyper link, its not hitting the events in UserControl ascx page. instead of that, i am getting reposted to same page

Main Page

```
RadDock dock6 = CreateRadDock();

dock6.Title = "Last Viewed Claims";
_userControl = LoadControl("~/pages/UserControl.ascx");
dock6.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(_userControl);
RadDockZone dz6 = (RadDockZone) RadDockZone1;
RadDockLayout1.Controls.Add(dock6);
dock6.Dock(dz6);
```

UserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserControl.ascx.cs" 

EnableViewState="true" Inherits="UserControl" %>

<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
<td>
            <asp:ListView ID="lvmydata" runat="server" >  
            <ItemTemplate >  
                <tr>  
                    <td>  
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'  
OnClick="linkClick">  
                        </asp:LinkButton>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>                   
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:ListView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UserControl.ascx.cs

```
public IList MyData
        {
            set
            {
               _myData = value;
                lvmyData.DataSource = _myData;
                lvmyData.DataBind();
                }

}
            get { return _lastViewedClaimsList; }
        }

protected void linkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton) sender;
            btn.CommandArgument = btn.Text;

          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add IDs to the controls you create dynamically and make sure you recreate them properly with each postback, preferably in the Page_Init event.

```
_userControl = LoadControl("~/pages/UserControl.ascx");
_userControl.ID = "theUserControlID";//that should not change across postbacks
dock6.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(_userControl);
//make sure the dock also has an ID that does not change
```